# Access Denied - Uploading/Downloading from s3 using External Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a folder/file-prefix within an s3-bucket that I wish to share with users from an external account.

I have applied the below policy to the bucket that has the folder/file-prefix that I wish to share. The external users are able to list objects within the folder of the s3 bucket, but are getting an 'Access Denied' error when attempting to upload or download objects to/from the bucket.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Test List Bucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "####-####-####"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": "<prefix>/*"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Test Upload Objects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "####-####-####"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/<prefix>/*"
     }
  ]
}
```

Any advice and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your policy is not valid because of `"s3:GetObject`. Please correct.

Comment: Thanks - typo corrected. Issue still remains

Comment: Is the account represented by`####-####-####` the same AWS account as owns the S3 bucket? If not, the IAM principals in the other account will need explicit S3 permissions for this S3 bucket in their IAM policies, in addition to this S3 bucket policy.

Comment: @Marley add the "s3:PutBucketAcl" as well

Comment: To test whether the problem lies in the policy, you could _temporarily_ grant access to `"Principal": "*"`. If that works, then you know the policy needs changing. If it doesn't fix things, then the users need additional permissions in _their_ IAM User settings to permit access to the bucket. (Permissions are required on _both_ the Bucket Policy and their IAM User for cross-account S3 access.)

Comment: @jarmod the account represented by `####-####-####` was for the external account. Confirming that by also adding explicit s3 permissions to the IAM principals in the other account, the external users can now get/put objects into it. Cheers all for the feedback and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IAM principal (role or user) to whom you are giving S3 bucket access is in the same AWS account as the S3 bucket then you can supply permission by either:

- an IAM policy on the IAM principal, or
- an S3 bucket policy

If the IAM principal is in a different AWS account to the S3 bucket (this is cross-account access) then you need to supply permission by both:

- an IAM policy on the IAM principal, and
- an S3 bucket policy

In your case, you are setting up cross-account access and you have correctly supplied the S3 bucket policy but you also need to add an appropriate IAM policy to the IAM principals (users or roles) in the other account that gives them S3 permissions on this specific S3 bucket.